# normal subgroups and factor group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is my question:

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H\triangleleft G$ a normal subgroup. Prove that $|G/H| =|G|$ if and only if $H = \{e\}$.

And this is my solution:

first we need to show that the $\{e\}$ is the subset of $H$ and indeed $\{e\}$ is the subset of $H$. Now let $G$ be a group if $H$ is a normal subgroup  of $G$ then there exist $a,  a^{-1}$ element of $H$ such that $(aH)(a^{-1}H)= (a  a^{-1})H=eH=H$.

Please check my solution.

Comment: Your solution does not appear to be complete. You should be proving two statements: one where you assume $|G/H| = |G|$ and then conclude (somehow, maybe using the answers below) that $H = \{e\}$, and another where you assume $H = \{e\}$ and then conclude that $|G/H| = |G|$.

Comment: Indeed, try the strategy @wckronholm suggested.  The second sentence in your proof is correct, but it doesn't actually say anything about the elements of $H$ (instead, it's just a true statement about how multiplication is defined in quotient groups).

Comment: @ wckronholm what about this solution.Consider G as a finite group and H as a normal subgroup then we assume that |G/H|=|G|, where |G|/|H| = |G|/1= |G| so therefore |H|= 1. On other hand we assume that H={e} thus |H|=1 which we want to show.

Comment: @ wckronholm  i think  i should rephrase the above  solution.Consider G as a finite group and H as a normal subgroup then we assume that |G/H|=|G|, where |G|/|H| = |G| only if  |H|= 1 so that  |G|/1= |G|. On other hand we assume that H={e} thus |H|=1 which we want to show.

Comment: Note, it's a consequence of Lagrange's theorem that $|G/H|=|G|/|H|$ for finite groups so you need to prove this if you haven't already been shown this result. If $H$ is non-trivial then $|H|\geq 2$ and so $|G/H|=|G|/|H|\leq \frac{1}{2}|G|<|G|$.

Comment: @Rust you mean to say that since it is a finite group then the order of the subgroup is the divisor of the order of the group. which means in this case the order of H is the divisor of the order of G. then that means the order  of a subgroup when it divide with the group G it must gives back the order of G. then there exist  only one number which is 1. so i must look for a subgroup which has the order one which actual the set of identity.

Comment: I meant what I said. My comment above is a valid proof of the contrapositive of the left to right implication.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\vert G/H\vert=\frac{\vert G\vert}{\vert H\vert}$, so $\vert G/H\vert=\vert G\vert$ if and only if $\vert H\vert=1$. This holds if and only if $H=\{e\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Lagrange's theorem - what is the definition of a factor group? The fact that $G$ is finite here is important as it is not true for infinite groups.